# How to load all the data in client side and perform pagination without going to server side?

Tags: jquery

I have fetching 20000 records from data base. now I need show those records in UI using pagination. I'm using jquery table pagination plugin.

I will load 20000 records when my page loads, I need to perform pagination in client side.How can i do this without going to server side for each request.

Comment: Don't do this. How long is it going to take to transfer all 20000 records at page load? What's the problem with making additional server requests? Transfer what you need for the first page and make further requests for the rest when you need them.

Comment: Im using datatables,if i pass json response can i use those operations in client side ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to use lazy loading on scroll down. Because this is effective way to show your data DataTable is option for you but once your data increased may be server not responding good.

Happy to help,
Amit Patel.

Comment: Thanks Amit,My problem is i have a pie chart, when i click  a slice on a pie it returns a value. i will filter the table using that value. Can this implement using the datatables?.can i use custom filter option in datatables?

Comment: I think you need to use indexing proper on your table. That way you get faster data. As well query should be optimized. Make more filter on chart will give you faster result. If all are not working you need to use xml data. This is last option to get back data faster then database.